# Filter a product by category

Tags: python, django, listview

I got two models. Products and categories. Every Product has a category and the categories have a slug. Now, when you call the url `'/catalog/adventure/'`, you should see a list with all products with the category 'adventure', when you write 'action', you should see Action-products etc.

So I made a listView

```
class BookListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'project/shop/product-list-view.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, path=self.kwargs['slug'])

        products = Product.objects.all().filter()

        return products
```

What do I have to write in .filter()?

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see your models here, but assuming that Product has a ForeignKey to Category, it should be as simple as:

```
    products = Product.objects.all().filter(category=category)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Product has a ForeignKey to Category, I would rather suggest to use backward relation with related_name:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   ...
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
   ...
```

and in your view:

```
products = category.products.all()
```

No filters are needed.